# Unable to execute dex: Literal out of range When external library export import

Tags: android, file, jar, external

I know that this question has been asked over and over again but still I've not been able    to find a helpful suggestion.When I add External Library and export and import then it gives error as "unable to execute dex". But when I deselect library in export import it run but give error as  "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError". I tried so many things But I unable to solved this issue please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> When I add External Library and export and import

That is not the appropriate way to add a JAR to an Android project. All you need to do is create a `libs/` directory in the project (if none exists) and put the JAR in this directory. Nothing else is needed. In particular, do *not* mess with your build path manually.

Comment: I was already put external jar file in Libs till I am not solved this.

Comment: @user3651987: What is the complete error message, and what is the JAR that you are trying to use that is giving you this error?

Comment: better you remove that from Libs/ ,try to import that External Library project to workspace and give external project as references to your project .

Comment: This is the error I got each time --> Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Literal out of range: 000000000000ffff
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Literal out of range: 000000000000ffff <--- and i am using Ksoap external jar file

Comment: @user3651987: Do you have lots of other JARs, or is this your only JAR?

Comment: I have lots of jar..but it runs on other machine